# Passing parameter from main window to pop-up Qdialog window

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have Qdialog with that I open from main window:

```
Dialog = myDialog(self)
```

Here is the code from new opened Dialog:

```
class myDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_DialogCalibration):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(myDialog, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
```

How can pass parameter(lint) from main window to this new window, something like

```
Dialog = myDialog(self, listInformation)
```

and then in myDialog class use that list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class myDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_DialogCalibration):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, listInfo):
        super(myDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.listInfo = listInfo
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Then, when you go to create the `myDialog`, you can add the list as a parameter. When you need to use it inside of your `myDialog`, you would access it as `self.listInfo`.

**EDIT:** To further expand on the comments:

If you have `def __init__(self, parent=None, listInfo=None)`, you would call it as `Dialog = myDialog(parent=self, listInfo=listInfo)`. If you had it as `def __init__(self, parent, listInfo)` you would do `Dialog = myDialog(self, listInfo)`. Hopefully you see the pattern here.

Comment: From main i call
   Dialog=myDialog(self, listinfo)
and when i write your code I got this error

TypeError: QDialog(QWidget parent=None, Qt.WindowFlags flags=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'

Comment: In fact, it is working when i popup dialog as
     Dialog=myDialog(listInfo)
and not passing self. Does it means I sholud never pass self as parameter when caliing popup window

Comment: My apologies. I see what you're doing. Try `Dialog = myDialog(self, listInfo, parent=self)` or change the `__init__` to `__init__(self, parent=None, listInfo=None)`, then use `Dialog = myDialog(parent=self, listInfo=listInfo)`, or something along those lines. Take a look into keyword and positional arguments in Python. Take a look at my updated answer.